# Validar si hay diferencia en horario PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array con datos. Deseo poder validar que no haya diferencia de horas por operario. La idea es encontrar que el la hora de termino no puede ser inferior a la hora de inicio.

```
  $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 001,
                  'start_hrs' => '07:30',
                  'end_hrs' => '15:30', );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 001,
                  'start_hrs' => '16:00',
                  'end_hrs' => '18:00', );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 002,
                  'start_hrs' => '07:30',
                  'end_hrs' => '15:00' );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 002,
                  'start_hrs' => '14:00', /*Error ya que trabajo hasta las 15:00 en otro turno */
                  'end_hrs' => '18:00', );
                    $current_end = 0;
                    $worker_id = 0;
                    foreach ($data as $val) {
                      echo $val['worker_id'];
                      echo "<br>";
                      if ($worker_id!=$val['worker_id']) {
                        if ($current_end > $val['start_hrs']) {

                          echo $val['start_hrs'];
                          echo "<br>";
                        }
                        $current_end = $val['end_hrs'];
                      } else {
                        $current_end = 0;
                      }
                      $worker_id = $val['worker_id'];
                    }
```

Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: La pregunta no es del todo clara, tampoco indica lo que has investigado/implementado para resolver este problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano la actualize un poco
Saludos

Comment: Si he entendido bien, quieres verificar que la hora de inicio del elemento siguiente no esté en la hora de fin del elemento anterior ¿? Si es eso, me pregunto por qué donde se originan los datos ha sido posible que ocurra este error, el cual deberás resolver ahora por código rompiéndote el coco. Sí, sí, **es un error el haber permitido que se creen datos de este modo** y si es posible deberías resolver esto en el origen, donde se generan los datos... Tan simple como desactivar las horas anteriores a las `15:00` si el usuario trabajó a esa hora para que no se pueda seleccionar la hora `14:00`

Comment: @A.Cedano es un aplicativo para que un operario ingrese su hora de producción mediante un trabajo en una maquina
Tu me recomiendas validar al momento de ingreso?

Comment: Pues claro. Hacer esto aquí sería en el fondo corregir un error que debió ser solventando/controlado al momento de ingresar los datos. No es simple hacerlo, porque tendrás que ir moviendo las filas para luego verificar si el inicio de un turno no incluye las horas del turno anterior (lo más simple sería quizá usar iteradores y esto podría ser costoso si son muchos datos), además, deberás comparar también cuando hay un cambio de `worker_id` ... La forma de evitar este error sería por ejemplo ir desactivando en el calendario o lo que sea que uses aquellas horas ya ocupadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es tan simple resolver este tipo de problemas a nivel de programación y, según el tamaño de los datos que estés manejando podría tener un impacto negativo sobre el rendimiento.

Considera implementar allí donde se introducen las horas una estrategia que vaya deshabilitando las franjas horarias, de modo que no pueda ser seleccionada una hora que ya esté comprendida en una franja horaria anterior. Esto no debería ser demasiado complicado.

Si los datos llegaron de ese modo a este punto estamos ante un error de lógica en otra capa de tu programa y ahora arrastras con este error rompiéndote el coco para resolverlo.

Dicho eso, no deja de ser una pregunta interesante. Aquí te dejo una forma de resolverlo usando Iteradores. Pero como ya dije, esto puede ser costoso si trabajas con muchos datos porque tendrás que recorrer todo de nuevo cuando debiste evitar el error en el origen y enviar tus datos limpios al servidor.

En este código creamos un array con las horas de entrada y de salida y un tercer valor que será `true` o `false` si la hora es superior o no. El código recoge además en el ìndice superior del array el valor de `worker_id`. Puedes organizar a `$outPut`  según aquello que te interese.

```
  $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 001,
                  'start_hrs' => '07:30',
                  'end_hrs' => '15:30', );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 001,
                  'start_hrs' => '16:00',
                  'end_hrs' => '18:00', );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 002,
                  'start_hrs' => '07:30',
                  'end_hrs' => '15:00' );
   $data[] = array(
                  'worker_id' => 002,
                  'start_hrs' => '14:00', /*Error ya que trabajo hasta las 15:00 en otro turno */
                  'end_hrs' => '18:00', );


$obj = new ArrayObject( $data );
$it = $obj->getIterator();
$outPut=array();

while( $it->valid() )
{
    #Referencia al elemento actual
    $current=$it->current();
    #Avanzamos el iterador
    $it->next();
    #Referencia al siguiente elemento
    $next=$it->current();
    #Verificamos que sea el mismo worker
    if($current['worker_id']==$next['worker_id']){
        #Comparamos fecha de fin actual con fecha de inicio siguiente
        $status=strtotime($current['end_hrs'])<strtotime($next['start_hrs']);
        $outPut[$current['worker_id']][]=array($current['end_hrs'],$next['start_hrs'],$status);
    }   
}
var_dump($outPut);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "15:30"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "16:00"
      [2]=>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "15:00"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "14:00"
      [2]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando funciones propias para arreglos.
Con `array_walk()` puedes acarrear el elemento anterior y compararlo con elemento actual.

```
// De una lista de worker_id 
foreach( array_unique(array_column($data, 'worker_id')) as $wid ){
   // Filtramos únicamente las entradas de cierto worker_id
   $worker = array_filter( $data, function($wh) use($wid) { return $wh['worker_id'] == $wid; } );
   array_walk( $worker
             , function( $v, $k, &$anterior){
                  if( $anterior['end_hrs'] > $v['start_hrs'] )
                     echo "Inválido $v[worker_id] ) $v[start_hrs]";
                  $anterior = $v;
               }
             , $anterior=null
             );
}
```